How to concave an object
I just started learning the program from scratch, and decided to start with a simple one. It turned out to be not at all simple. How can I repeat a similar shape as in the photo?


There are many ways of approaching, one of the simplest is to create a circle (16 vertices, in my example)

Then extrude on X axis, then extrude on X and scale, then extrude on X and scale, .....

Then add some edge loops with Ctrl R, then scale all on Y axis.

